# Umano AndroidSlidingUpPanel how to disable touch when panel is visible?

Tags: java, android

So the problem i have is that when the panel slides up and i touch somewhere it closes the panel.

How can i disable touch so that i can only drag the panel to open and close it?

This is the library: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Thanks,

Vince

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution,i'm not sure if this is how it's done but it works.

**This disables touch for the whole slide panel**

```
mSlideUpPanel.getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(null);
```

**mBottomSheet** is the dragview you drag up to show the panel.

If you want you can just add an onclicklistener to the dragview so you can also click on the bottomsheet to open/close it.

```
mBottomSheet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mSlideUpPanel != null &&
                    (mSlideUpPanel.getPanelState() == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED || mSlideUpPanel.getPanelState() == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.ANCHORED)) {
                mSlideUpPanel.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.EXPANDED);
            }
            if (mSlideUpPanel != null &&
                    (mSlideUpPanel.getPanelState() == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.EXPANDED || mSlideUpPanel.getPanelState() == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.ANCHORED)) {
                mSlideUpPanel.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED);
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: mSlideUpPanel.getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(null); is not working for me. Any updated solution?

Comment: @user1090751 weird for me it works fine can you post your code so i can take a look.